# Creating an Amazon Authorization Signature with TideSDK

Tags: javascript, tidesdk

I'm trying to piecemeal together a S3 client for TideSDK. I've gotten past the date formating/matching, the string to sign - but I am now getting the error **SignatureDoesNotMatch**

I've tried just about every angle I could think of but still coming up short. Maybe one of you can find the errors of my ways. Note: AWS is defined elsewhere.

```
var podcastFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(AWS.fileName);
var fileContents = podcastFile.read();

AWS.http = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
AWS.fileURL = 'http://'+AWS.AWSBucketName+'.s3.amazonaws.com/show.json';        
AWS.http.setTimeout(AWS.timeout);
AWS.http.open('PUT', AWS.fileURL, false);

var mimeType = 'text/json';
var fileName = 'show.json';
var curDate = AWS.Date.formatDate(new Date(),'E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss') + ' -0400';
var StringToSign = 'PUT\n\n'+mimeType+'\n' + curDate + '\n/'+AWS.AWSBucketName+'/' + fileName;

var AWSAccessKeyID = 'AWS ' + AWS.APIKey + ':';
var AWSSignature = Ti.Codec.digestHMACToHex(Ti.Codec.SHA1, AWS.SecretKey, StringToSign);
var AWSAuthHeader = AWSAccessKeyID.concat(AWSSignature);

AWS.http.setRequestHeader('Authorization', AWSAuthHeader); 
AWS.http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/json');
AWS.http.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', podcastFile.size().toString());
AWS.http.setRequestHeader('Host', 's3.amazonaws.com');
AWS.http.setRequestHeader('Date', curDate);
AWS.http.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip');
AWS.http.setRequestHeader('Proxy-Connection','close');

var headers = AWS.http.getResponseHeaders();
console.log(AWS.http.send(fileContents));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the tidesdk, but you need to base64 encode your AWSSignature.

I was having a similar issue, and this tool helped me: http://aws.amazon.com/code/199.